# "Branching" out progress across different processes (loops)

Tags: c#, branch, progress

**Objective**

I'm trying to build a progress tracking mechanism which supports "branching".

**Abstract**

The principal concept here is that at every stage I know the current index and count of steps till this stage is complete.

**Sample Scenario**

```
var tasks = new Task[]
{
    new Task(5),  // 5 sub tasks
    new Task(2),  // 2 sub tasks
};
```

Assuming these items are run serially, progress percentage would look as follows:

```
0%
    10%
    20%
    30%
    40%
    50%
50%
    75%
    100%
100%
```

**Question Time!**

First of all, what are the correct terms for what I'm doing? I have been unable to properly search because of this.

Secondly, what are the mathematics of what I'm doing? What are the variables that I have to track?

**Final Product**

I would like to end up with an interface that looks like this:

```
class TaskManagerExample
{
    void Execute(Task[] tasks)
    {
        var pm = new ProgressManager(); // <- this class does the magic

        // v-- and this is how the magic is used :)
        pm.ProgressChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value = (sender as ProgressManager).TotalProgress;
        };

        pm.SetTotal(tasks.Length);

        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            task.Execute(pm.Branch());
            pm.NextStep();
        }
    }
}

class Task
{
    protected int SubTasks = 0;
    public Task(int subTasks){ this.SubTasks = subTasks; }

    public void Execute(ProgressManager pmb)
    {
        pmb.SetTotal(this.SubTasks);

        for(int i = 0; i < this.SubTasks; i++)
        {
            // do something
            pmb.NextStep();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the implementation for `ProgressManager`. I've been able to achieve a parent-child relation so `Branch()` and `NextStep()` are ok. I'm mostly confused about how `TotalProgress` should be implemented.
How would one go through the tree to calculate the right progress position?

Comment: Would you be able to add another property to the Task with the amount of effort would be required (estimate), and use the aggregated efforts to come up with an estimate of percentage?

Comment: No, for several reasons: 1. My current use won't work with it. 2. It is cleaner to keep this info at the class responsible for it (progress rather than the task). 3. To make branching somewhat cleaner and more obvious.

Comment: Task shouldn't know about who its reporting its progress to, you should implement `Progress<T>` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx), and then handle the events in the Task Manager. The task manager can track the current step and the progress (0 to 100%) of the currently running task. The task manager can also implement `Progress<T>` and the calculation is simple, current progress = (current step * current step progress) / # of steps.

Comment: @RonBeyer I agree with what you said except one part...I have sub tasks. A single task would have to act like a `TaskManager`. The top task manager does not know about subtasks. I need an implementation that can work with this sort of relation at any level.

Comment: A sub-task can calculate the progress the same way, by using its sub tasks progress to calculate and update its own. At that point though, the task manager becomes almost exactly the same as a Task and therefore all you really need is the Task class...

Comment: @RonBeyer But the sub-task has to report back to the main progress manager. Also, as I mentioned already, there might be more than two levels...

Comment: Right, what I'm saying is that the progress manager and the tasks should not really care about each other. Inheriting from `Progress<T>` means that *whatever* is listening to the progress can get updates, be it a "progress manager" or a UI. If a Task can have sub-tasks, the constructor should take an `IEnumerable<Task>` for the sub-tasks, which can then have any level. The math cascades in that the top task gets notification about its sub tasks, which get notifications of its sub tasks ad infinitum. I'll post a sample `Task` class here in a few minutes.

Comment: @Christian I apologize I have to run, but you can see my progress here: http://pastebin.com/XPLRJNuq I was working on getting the progress value to report correctly up, but you can see where I was going...